# Linux default ACLs do not respect creating new files

Tags: linux, acl

I have a few ACLs set to a dir `/app/certs`

```
[root@someserver certs]# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:jenkins:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:jenkins:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:controlm:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

When creating a directory all ACLs as inherited as expected

```
[root@someserver certs]# mkdir test-dir

[root@someserver certs]# getfacl test-dir/
# file: test-dir/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:jenkins:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:jenkins:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:controlm:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

But creating a "simple" file will overwrite all ACLs set:

```
[root@someserver certs]# touch test-file

[root@someserver certs]# getfacl test-file
# file: test-file
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:jenkins:rwx                #effective:r--
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:controlm:rwx              #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

Why so or did I missunderstood the concept of ACLs?